# Save styled element to reuse in other view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, styling

I'm making an iOS app with Xcode where all my buttons should have the same style. The only difference between these buttons are their height and width. Is there a way to save the first one I styled, and then use it again in the different view controllers, without copying? I'm thinking if this is possible it'll save me a lot of time.

Comment: have you tried subclassing?

Comment: are you doing all this in the interface builder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying the same style to multiple instances of `UIButton`:

---

### **Strictly Programmatic route:**

The first two methods are what I would do. The third is only to illustrate that it is possible to write an `init` that copies settings from another button.

**Apply preset style with a sub class:**

```
class StyledButton : UIButton {        

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        // more styling
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Apply preset style with an extension to UIButton:**

```
extension UIButton {

    func setCustomStyle1() {

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        // nore styling

    }
}
```

**Copy style with a convenience init in an extension to UIButton:**

```
extension UIButton {

    convenience init(styleFromButton button: UIButton, frame: CGRect) {

        self.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = button.backgroundColor

    }
}
```

---

### **Interface Builder solution:**

Create a new Swift file:

[image]
[image]

Create a sub class of `UIButton` in the new file:

```
class StyledButton : UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        style()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        style()
    }

    private func style() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        // more styling
    }
}
```

Go back to the **Interface Builder** and select a `UIButton` you want to style.
Select the third panel on the right, this is the **identity inspector**.
Select your sub class as the class for the `UIButton`.

Repeat for all buttons to style.

[image]

---

Or style the entire thing in **IB** and Alt-Drag to make a copy.

Comment: Hi @RMenke. I think I get your idea and solution. I'll try out your solution tomorrow at work, and give a feedback afterwards. Thank you very much.

Comment: HI @RMenke. I copied your StyledButton class, but gets errors like "Use of undeclared type 'UIButton'"

Comment: @LocDaiLe `import UIKit`

Comment: This solution works very well, thank you! But how come I can't see my style for the buttons in storyboard? But everything works as it should in the simulators.

Comment: @LocDaiLe That is because the core of your app is actually the code and not the IB. The IB is part of your code base, not the other way around. So it makes sense that you don't see the subclass rendered. It would also seriously slow down the IB.

Comment: Okay i get that. Another thing is what is the different between the override init and required?